# full text search with multiple tokens in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6

Given that I have multiple documents contains a sentence such as "welcome to how are you doing today?" I applied a `simple_query_string` query to search the above sentence. When I first use `welcome to how`. It returns 0 hit. However, when I use `how are you doing today` it shows all the documents. Can someone tell me what causes this?

the query is like:

query: {
    simple_query_string : {
                            query: '\ welcome to \',
                            fields : ['content'],
                            default_operator: 'AND' }
                       }

The settings for the analyzer are:

```
{
  "number_of_shards": 2,
  "refresh_interval": "30s",
  "analysis": {
    "filter": {
      "autocomplete_filter": {
        "type": "edge_ngram",
        "min_gram": 1,
        "max_gram": 20
      }
    },
    "analyzer": {
      "charSplit": {
        "type": "custom",
        "tokenizer": "ngram_tokenizer",
        "char_filter": [
          "my_char_filter"
        ],
        "filter": [
          "lowercase",
          "autocomplete_filter"
        ]
      }
    },
    "tokenizer": {
      "ngram_tokenizer": {
        "type": "nGram",
        "min_gram": "1",
        "max_gram": "1"
      }
    },
    "char_filter": {
      "my_char_filter": {
        "type": "mapping",
        "mappings": "specialCharacters"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: add the query you used for searching

Comment: Also add the mapping of your index.

Comment: @AndreyBorisko I have updated the post

Comment: @NishantSaini mapping type is text

Comment: Why have you placed backslash in query? You have mentioned that type of `content` is text. What is the analyzer for the same?